# OutOfMemory in Android

Tags: android, memory-management

In the solution for out of memory: [Strange out of memory issue while loading an image to a Bitmap object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477572/android-strange-out-of-memory-issue), it talks about using: decodeFile(File f). How do you handle internal image files that are referred to as R.id.something? these resources are seen as integers?

Answer (score 2):

You can use decodeResource():

```
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.id.someimage);
```

or

`Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.id.someimage,options);`